# Check if property exists in an object inside array in JSONB field in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Here is my table data:

Corresponding sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e3f09

```
create table jsonData (
    id serial primary key,
    data jsonb
);

insert into jsonData (data) values (

$${
  "b": 2,
  "c": [
    {
      "d": {
        "e": true
      }
    },
    {
      "d": {
        "e": true
      }
    },
    {
      "d": {
        "e": true,
        "f": "I'm here"
      }
    }
  ]
}
$$::jsonb),
(
$${
  "a": 1,
  "c": [
    {
      "d": {
        "e": true
      }
    },
    {
      "d": {
        "e": true
      }
    },
    {
      "d": {
        "e": true
      }
    }
  ]
}$$::jsonb);
```

The question is - how do I select all records, where "f" property (path is the same everywhere - 'c -> d -> f') exists?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an `EXISTS` in which you use `jsonb_array_elements()` to get the arrays' elements and check `->'d'->'f'` for `NULL`.

```
SELECT * 
       FROM jsonData
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM jsonb_array_elements(data->'c')
                            WHERE value->'d'->'f' IS NOT NULL);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e3f09/8)

Comment: hmm, any idea how to index this query?

Comment: Did you manage to create an index for that?

Comment: For an index, you would usually want to leverage a `gin` index.  Given table `jsonData` and a `json` type column named `data`, it'd look like this: `create index "jsonData_data_gin" on "jsonData" using gin("data");`.